# How To Have Source Code On Mac PC But Run It On A Simulator On Windows PC?

Tags: android-studio, ssh, android-emulator, adb, simulator

I have a Mac Book Pro and another Windows laptop and I have Android Studio installed and configured on both of them. What I need is to run my Android project on Mac but connect it to the simulator on Windows! Is it possible? If yes how?

Comment: Do you use Git or another version control system?

Comment: The adb connection to an emulator is just a TCP connection. If you expose the necessary port(s) on the emulator machine you should be able to do an `adb connect` on the other and use the remote device just like a local emulator.

Comment: Check https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/tools/android/adb_remote_setup.sh

Comment: @JimRedmond I use Git